# How to create an array with a JsonBuilder in groovy

Tags: arrays, json, groovy, jsonbuilder

I would like to use closure way to make following json:

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "key": "testkey",
            "value": "testvalue"
        }
    ]
}
```

I'm using following syntax:

```
new JsonBuilder().root {
        'key'(testKey)
        'value'(testValue)
}
```

But it produces:

```
{
    "root": {
        "key": "testkey",
        "value": "testvalue"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your example works correctly, because you pass a simple map for `root` key. You have to pass a list instead do produce expected output. Consider following example:

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder

def builder = new JsonBuilder()
builder {
    root((1..3).collect { [key: "Key for ${it}", value: "Value for ${it}"] })
}

println builder.toPrettyString()
```

In this example we pass a list of elements created with `(1..3).collect {}` to a `root` node. We have to split initialization from building a JSON body, because things like `new JsonBuilder().root([])` or even `builder.root([])` throw an exception, because there is no method that expects a parameter of type `List`. Defining list for node `root` inside the closure solves this problem.

#### Output

```
{
    "root": [
        {
            "key": "Key for 1",
            "value": "Value for 1"
        },
        {
            "key": "Key for 2",
            "value": "Value for 2"
        },
        {
            "key": "Key for 3",
            "value": "Value for 3"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: can I do it also for one element collection?

Comment: @pixel Yes. The number of elements in collection does not matter.

Answer (score 6):

You can write something like below:

```
def json = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()
json  { 
  root (
   [
       {
        key ('color')
        value ('orange')
     }
   ]
  )
}

println json.toPrettyString()
```

Notice how array is passed to `root` in the above.